# Bokeh Line from AjaxDataSource disappearing on 'replace' update

Tags: python, bokeh

I am using Bokeh to render a stock price chart that updates by polling for json updates. Strangely, the line graph disappears when using the 'replace' mode on the AjaxDataSource. I can tell it's still there, because there is a HoverTool that still shows the data when it is hovered over. As soon as the first poll is executed and the data is fed back, the line becomes invisible.

```
# price ajax endpoint
def Data(request, ticker):
    prices = RealtimeStockPrice.objects.filter(ticker=ticker).order_by('last_time')
    x = []
    y = []
    for p in prices:
        x.append(p.last_time.astimezone(timezone('US/Eastern')))
        y.append(float(p.last_price))

    return JsonResponse({'time': x, 'price': y})


# bokeh plotting code
p1 = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", title="Realtime {} Prices".format(signal.ticker))
source = AjaxDataSource(data_url=data_url, polling_interval=10000, mode='replace')
source.data = dict(time=times, price=prices)

# missing line:
p1.line(x='time', y='price', source=source, line_width=3, line_color='#22d18f')

# visible lines:
p1.line(static_times, trigger_price, line_width=2, line_dash='dotted', color='#e14646')
p1.line(static_times, open, line_width=2, line_dash='dotted', color='grey')
```

[plot with the line invisible using 'replace'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU4sf.png)

when I change the AjaxDataSource's mode='replace' to mode='append', the line is visible once again.

[plot with the line visible using 'append'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KyOx.png)

Is it possible the ajax updates are overwriting the color or visibility/alpha? I would also appreciate any suggestions for debugging this problem, because I do not know how to get visibility into the html canvas goings-on.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you verified conclusively that the `x` and `y` lists in your JSON response have more than a single element? `replace` mode does exactly what it says—it replaces all the current data with the data in the reponse. So if your response contains zero or one points, the existing line will be replaced with "no line" (as expected).

Comment: Thanks for your response! yes, I can log on both the server side as well as the browser js console that the json responses contain at least as many elements as the prior AJAX request. for both the dates (x axis) and prices (y axis)

Comment: additionally as mentioned I can see that the points are still being loaded in the rendered chart, as the Hovertool still shows the points when they are hovered over, so they are not being overwritten by an empty list :/

Comment: Can't really say anything more without a complete, minimal reproducer to actually run and investigate.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone sees this, I believe it was because Bokeh requires ajax updates for timeseries to be in microseconds since epoch :(

https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/cK4MihXn7JM
https://github.com/hhprogram/PyramidSite/blob/master/webgraphing/views/ajaxView.py

I was able to slap .timestamp() on all my datetime values on my x axis and it worked.
e.g. for ajax endpoint

```
def Data(request, ticker):
    prices = RealtimeStockPrice.objects.filter(ticker=ticker).order_by('last_time')
    x = []
    y = []
    for p in prices:
        x.append(p.last_time.astimezone(timezone('US/Eastern')).timestamp())
        y.append(float(p.last_price))

    return JsonResponse({'time': x, 'price': y})
```